# Clone Device To Multiple Devices

Tags: backup, restore, android-go

I have to set up and configure a thousand devices that use Android Go 8.1.

Every device is the same brand and same model.

I have to install two third-party APKs that get thrown a warning by Play Protect. I also have to configure certain settings, Pass Code, disabling background mobile data for certain apps....Notification settings and so forth. Everything on every phone needs to be precisely the same, down to the pass code, and down to the GMail address the device is logged in with.

I have no experience in Rooting. I need some advice on how I would achieve this in the fastest way possible. The device is a generic Hisense U605 with 1GB RAM and 8GB internal storage.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! For starters, please see: [Bulk Android Device Provisioning](/q/136172/16575) // [Clone and distribute Android 4 device with preloaded applications](/q/32687/16575) // [Clone Android device including the content of SD card](/q/22631/16575). As every device is the same brand and model, you could eg use the "Nandroid approach" – but that would require you to unlock the bootloader and install a custom recovery (eg [tag:twrp]). I'm not sure if you'd be fine with that.

Comment: Hopefully your devices are bought with zero-touch enrollment support: https://developers.google.com/zero-touch Otherwise it will be a lot of manual work...